# Temporary variable that reset on startup in MySQL

Tags: mysql

How to define a global variable that will be reset when MySQL starts?
Meaning it is temporary for the MySQL process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you use MySQL-8.0 [presistent system variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/persisted-system-variables.html), all global variables are for the duration of the mysqld process only and will revert to the default my.cnf/ini settings upon restart.

Comment: Is there an alternative way that is equivalent to define a global variable that is user-defined? since mysql 5.5 user-defined global variable is no longer allowed.

Comment: store in a table.

Comment: How to make it temporary so that it will be reset on startup :P

Comment: store it with unix timestamp and check if current based on `> NOW() - uptime` (uptime from GLOBAL STATUS). Maybe more scope of objective might hint to a better solution. Is this key management for encrypting fields?